# Best way to design a from/to routing entry view (similar to maps)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, user-interface, uiview, user-experience

I am trying to design a view that takes in from and to locations from the user. Here is what I have so far:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbr3y.jpg

As you can see, the view is nothing but HORRENDOUS and UGLY. Any idea how to make it pretty :)? I am open for suggestions that will move things around however I am skeptical about having separate views for the from and then to input.

Thank you!

Edit: The to/from labels will show the chosen locations from the tableview entries and the blue buttons enable the user to edit the location again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Line up the colons of "from:" and "to:" - i.e. indent "To:"
2. Make "Go" slightly smaller so it doesn't look so crowded.
3. Add some color to the Go button.
4. Switch to a different state than California :-)

Comment: Kind sir,
what do you think of this improved setup? http://oi53.tinypic.com/24nqofp.jpg